# Explanation of the following date format 2012-08-08T15:04:33+0200

Tags: date, datetime, time

Can someone explain me the following date format?

```
2012-08-08T15:04:33+0200
```

I suppose

```
2012-08-08 // should be year-month-day 

15:04:33 // is hour:minutes:seconds

+0200 // should be the Timezone offset
```

I have no idea about `T` meaning.

Answer (score 3):

T signifies that everything following is Time

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your breakdown, the T is just a separator from date and time.